# Does Windows Azure ACS support username / password auth?

Tags: azure, acs

I am looking at Windows Azure ACS as an alternative to implementing my own username / password scheme in my app.   This will be a publicly available website.

In addition to using SSO providers such as Google or Facebook, can I use Windows Azure ACS to support username/password authentication?

I see that it supports Active Directory as a provider.  I am not sure this is the right thing as I have always thought of Active Directory as an "enterprise" provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Azure ACS does not support username/password authentication in the form you need. Shahin outlined it in details.

Your options really are:

- [Windows Azure Active Directory](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/identity/) (WAAD)
- [Identity Server](http://thinktecture.github.io/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/) (IdSVR)

While classic on-premises Active Directory deployed with a Domain Controller option is indeed quite enterprisy, WAAD is not exact copy of the same in the Cloud. I would actually recommend that you give a shot and try out. Using the [WAAD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx) you can fully automate user management in WAAD.

Your second option is based on IdSVR. This is full-featured Identity Server and Security Token Service. It is developed against the best practices in security and is quite easily extensible! While it does not provide out of the box support for user management (user registration, password reset, etc.) it is ASP.NET MVC 4 application. So you can very easily add this features yourself. There actually is [an open enhancement planned for User Management API and UI](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/212).

Both WAAD and IdSVR integrate well with ACS, so you can provide seamless support for social identities along with own login.

Another service that is still in Beta/Preview is the [SocialSTS project](http://socialsts.azurewebsites.net/). It is kind of extension to Azure ACS and is designed to help you add more identity providers (such as LinkedIn, Twitter, GitHUB, Amazon Login, etc) to your Access Control Service.

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate directly with the ACS by using [Service Identities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185945.aspx), but they are not intended to be used for end-user authentication, as the page explains:

> Service identities are not intended to be used as end-user credentials. In ACS, service identities are most commonly used in REST web service scenarios, over the OAuth WRAP protocol, where a client requests a SWT token directly from ACS to present to the web service.

I believe this is the only way to directly get a token from the ACS.